# multiple string input from file , awk command

Tags: shell, unix

### multiple input values from file

i have this command

```
   $ awk ' $0=="string_start" { inSection=1 } inSection; $0=="string_end" { nSection=0 }' input_file.txt >> output_file.txt
```

if possible how can i have multiple input values from list in  **string_start_file.txt** append all the output to a **output_file.txt**.

Example **string_start_file.txt**

```
string_start_1
string_start_2
string_start_3
string_start_4
string_start_5
string_start_6
string_start_7
```

- Note string_end is always the same.

so it kinda dose this

```
       $ awk ' $0=="string_start1" { inSection=1 } inSection; $0=="string_end" { nSection=0 }' input_file.txt >> output_file.txt
   $ awk ' $0=="string_start2" { inSection=1 } inSection; $0=="string_end" { nSection=0 }' input_file.txt >> output_file.txt
   $ awk ' $0=="string_start3" { inSection=1 } inSection; $0=="string_end" { nSection=0 }' input_file.txt >> output_file.txt
   $ awk ' $0=="string_start4" { inSection=1 } inSection; $0=="string_end" { nSection=0 }' input_file.txt >> output_file.txt
```

thanks ;)

Comment: What is the logic behind this script? Please post a sample output too.

Comment: Please, also, consider rephrasing your question. Could it be rephrased like this: `I have a file 'string_start_file.txt' I wish to grab its lines and prefix each line before the corresponding line in 'input_file.txt' and append the output to 'output_file.txt'`. I am not sure if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i have multiple input values from list in **string_start_file.txt**

You can read the start strings in a BEGIN block, make each string an array *index* and then simply use the `in` operator to check it:

```
awk 'BEGIN {while (getline <"string_start_file.txt" > 0) starts[$0]=1}
     $0 in starts {inSection=1} inSection; $0=="string_end" {inSection=0}' input_file.txt
```